# android doInBackground

Tags: android, background, download

hi to all 
how can i make this code to wait until it finishes downloading the image

with what can i replace `doInBackground(URL... paths)` to make it wait to download then continue with the rest of the code

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Bitmap> {
    // This class definition states that DownloadImageTask will take String
    // parameters, publish Integer progress updates, and return a Bitmap
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... paths) {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = paths[0];
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            int length = connection.getContentLength();
            InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
            byte[] imageData = new byte[length];
            int buffersize = (int) Math.ceil(length / (double) 100);
            int downloaded = 0;
            int read;
            while (downloaded < length) {
                if (length < buffersize) {
                    read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, length);
                } else if ((length - downloaded) <= buffersize) {
                    read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, length
                            - downloaded);
                } else {
                    read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, buffersize);
                }
                downloaded += read;
                publishProgress((downloaded * 100) / length);
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                    length);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap created");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap not created");
            }
            is.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Malformed exception: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        String name = ImageLink.substring(ImageLink
                .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        if (result != null) {
            hasExternalStoragePublicPicture(name);
            saveToSDCard(result, name);
            isImage = true;

        } else {
            isImage = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense. `doInBackground()` *is* downloading the image. It cannot wait for itself to finish.

Comment: @CommonsWare: i want the rest of the code to wait for the download to finish i dont want the code to continue until the image is done because im downloading more than 1 image and for some reason they overlap and i end up with 2 images which are the same...?!

Comment: Show the code where you are creating your DownloadImageTask instances. Are you creating multiple instances? If so, that could be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[doInBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29)) executes in the background. The part that `waits for the download` and `continues with the rest of the code` is [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29). This is the function you're probably asking for.

Comment: this is correct, the AsyncTask usage dictactes that when doInBackground completes it triggers onPostExecute().  This is all in the background so you will have to inform your UI Thread that the task has finished and that it can load the image from memory or something.

Comment: DSouza: i added the onPostExecute() and still same problem....???! i updated the code up on my original question

Answer (score 0):

The point about AsyncTask is the main code in your Activity (which creates the AsyncTask) doesn't wait. Async is short for asynchronous - that means something which happens without a pre-determined time-frame.

If you want to have a download or multiple downloads complete before other code can execute then you either need to perform things in a synchronous manner (not good in Android Activities) or you need to write your code to wait on a callback.